# VBA webscraper stopped working on unexpected reason

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am coding VBA web-scraping software to grab products names from web and add them into Excel worksheet. This code was working fine a minute ago and then all of a sudden it stopped scraping the information. Any ideas what might be the problem? Website is still up and running and no inspected variables have been changed. Here is my code:

```
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, x As Long

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/pc+hardware/grafikkarten+pc+hardware/amdati/rx+6600+amdati/", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Do
x = x + 1
On Error Resume Next
Cells(x + 1, 1) = html.querySelectorAll("div.product_name a")(x - 1).innerText
Loop Until Err.Number = 91
```

I even recovered last save which was working 100% too and now it doesn't. I have not added anything else to the code nor changed references.

Is it possible that after multiple tests webpages block data scraping for some times?

Comment: Take out `On Error Resume Next` - do you get any errors? Where does the code stop?

Comment: @BruceWayne Doing so gives me run-time error 91. "Object variable or With block not set".

Comment: Okay, i was afk from computer for 30 mins, and now it's working again.... Must be some network problem from scraped website. What a brain teaser...

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem with this code and this specific website is that if you do multiple query's very often then you will be locked out for uncertain time.